# Execute PHP command from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on Windows. I'm trying to call a specific form (which is saved on different location) with JavaScript/PHP.

File `D:\Test\Form.php` looks like this:

```
<form action="D:\Test\submit.php" method="post">
    <select name="application">
        <option value="name">Enter your name</option>
        <option value="last name">Enter your last name</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

My main page looks like this:

```
<html>
    <script srv="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <body>
        <form method = 'post'>
            <select>
                <option value="application">application</option>
                <option value="payment">payment</option>
            </select>
        </form>

        <button onClick="createDiv">click me</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    $htmlstring = shell_exec("type D:\Test\Form.php");
    //$htmlstring = "hello world";
?>
```

I have this JavaScript:

```
<script>
function createDiv()
{
    var htmlstring = "<?php echo $htmlstring; ?>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = htmlstring;
}
</script>
```

When I press F12 I can see that the form has been generated but I cannot see it on the page when I click the button, however when I uncomment the "hello world" it will print it and everything seems to be working just fine except printing the form itself...

The main idea was to generate a button that will "add" the form I was choosing from the list endlessly (either: "application/payment")

How to create this either using JS or PHP itself?

Comment: What's wrong with `require` or using Ajax (if you don't want to load the form on page load)?

Comment: Btw, `action="D:\Test\submit.php"` won't work since you're telling the form to load that file directly into the browser, not going through the web server. Browsers can't run PHP. All PHP code are executed on the server and then the result from that are returned to the browser.

Comment: Hey Magnus, i want to load that page on the same page (the home page itself)
i dont know how Ajax works sadly.
regarding to your action = "D:\Test\submit.php" the submit is a different thing which sends you to a different page thats correct, but im not on this stage.

Comment: Then you should be able to use [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).

Comment: Hey Magnus, seems like the require works exactly as shell_exec.
the idea is to click a button and it will print that same page which i want to do.
for example:
`<?php
$htmlstring = "type D:\Test\Form.php";
?>`

and the JS goes like this:
`<script>
function createDiv()
{
var htmlstring = "<?php require($htmlstring)?>";
document.getElementById("demo".innerHTML = htmlstring;
}
</script>`

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, I would really recommend using jQuery `load` or one of the other ajax methods (https://api.jquery.com/load/), it's a far more "normal" way than what you're doing here. Here's an example using jQuery `get` to give you an idea (won't work since the php file being referenced doesn't exist): https://jsfiddle.net/b0vtxjz7/

Comment: There are some big differences between your current version, require and ajax. The code you have now will load all contents of the file form.php into a variable. Any PHP code you have won't be executed but treated as text (it will be outputted to the page). `require` will load the contents but still treat PHP as PHP and will be executed in the context of the page you include it into. With ajax, you will make a request to the web server to get the file and any PHP code will be executed on the server before being returned to your file.

Comment: Hey Bretty I tried your solution:
$(".createDiv").click(function(){
   $.get("D:\Test\Form.php",function(output){
      $("#demo").append(dados);
    });
});

done nothing, have i done something wrong?
clueless when it comes to ajax =/ tried to figure out what im looking at.

Comment: @CurrentRedemption Let's continue is chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207991/60265234

Comment: @CurrentRedemption I had a typo in the jsfddle, updated here: https://jsfiddle.net/2qmnkzyd/

But let's continue in that chat link I posted above

Comment: @Brett Gregson
seems like the problem was with the file location:
"Your file.php file should be in the same directory as the current file being executed. Also this all needs to run through a web server"

when i tried to call the php file from a different location: such as D:\Test\Form.php
i got an error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/Test/Form.php' from origin 'localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,chrome,chrome-extension,https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so thanks to Brett Gregson, i was managed to solve my issue with an ajax.
sadly i dont understand how it works completly but i will make some reading regarding and hope to chat with him and he might explain that to me, for those that understand how ajax works and looking for the same solution here is the code:

```
<html>
<script srv="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <select>
                <option value="application">application</option>
                <option value="payment">payment</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <button class="createDiv">Click me</button>
        <p id="demo"></p> #this also can be <div id="demo"></div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(".createDiv").click(function(){
        $.get("Test\Form.php",function(output){
            $("#demo").append(output);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure we can pass parameters and create some if loops, all i've left to figure is why when i press F12 i don't see the "form" appears there.

hope it will help others.